# OTRS Attachment Uploader

Tags: file, attachment, uploader, otrs

I am new to OTRS and I am still familiarizing myself with the platform. Recently for some particular reason the attachment uploader started not to work - basically whenever a file is attached, the page refreshes and the file is lost. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: What version are you using? What brower version? the next step would be to look at the error logs and use firebug to look into it. mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem might be the file permissions on the server side. Please see my comment above and provide more details.